# Round mode returning wrong value only for certain numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, rounding

I've just encountered a strange behaviour in my function I use to round.

The function simply does:

```
CAST(ROUND(@numerator / CONVERT(REAL, @denominator) * 100 ,1,1) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '%'
```

which I use to diplay a percentage.
It works perfecly but if I pass 57 or 58 as numerator and 100 as denominator, what I get as result is 56.9 or 57.9. I can vaguely understand the reason behind it (before getting truncated the result is 56.99999999...) but why does it happen just with those numbers and not for example with 55/100?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That is how the vagaries of floating point numbers.  Use `numeric`/`decimal`.

Comment: Mmm I do use float numbers